# Can IP header be at different offset across different machines?

Tags: linux, networking, pcap, libpcap

I'm writing a tool with libpcap to analyze TCP traffic. The problem I'm facing is that inside a pcap file that was provided to me for testing, I see the IP header starts at offset 0x10 (hence after 16 bytes), while all the documentation + live capture show me that it's always at 0xE (like the documentation claims).

How I try to get a hold of the ip and tcp header:

```c
struct iphdr *ip;
struct tcphdr *tcp;
ip = (struct iphdr *)(packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
tcp = (struct tcphdr *)(packet + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr)
```

Some wireshark images:

Live capture - [image]

As you can see it starts after 14 bytes, like it should

offline dump file - [image]

Dump file ip header starts after 16 bytes

What is the correct way to parse the IP and TCP header?

Thanks

Comment: That depends completely on the data-link protocol. Different data-link protocols have different frame header sizes, and even with the same data-link protocol, you can have different frame sizes. For example, an ethernet header is normally 14 octets, but with 802.1Q tagging, it is 18 octets. Also, Wi-Fi frame headers are different than ethernet headers, and other data-link protocols have very different headers.

Comment: Probably a question better suited for [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Ron Maupin is 100% correct.  To give some more details:

> The problem I'm facing is that inside a pcap file that was provided to me for testing

[The pcap-savefile(5) man page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-savefile.5.html) indicates that one of the fields in the pcap file header is the "Link-layer header type" field; as the man page says:

> a 4-byte number giving the link-layer header type for packets in the capture; see pcap-linktype(7) for the LINKTYPE_ values that can appear in this field.

If you have opened a capture file with [`pcap_open_offline()` or one of the variants thereof](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_open_offline.3pcap.html), [the `pcap_datalink()` routine](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_datalink.3pcap.html) in libpcap will return the link-layer header type.

The link-layer header type is a *requirement* for interpreting the contents of a packet.  For IP packets, for example, the IP header comes after any metadata headers and the link-layer header, and not all metadata headers (if present) and not all link-layer headers have the same length, so you *must* know what link-layer header is present in order to know where the IP header begins - or, in fact, to even determine whether the packet is an IP packet!  For Ethernet packets, for example, you must look at the Ethernet type/length field to see whether it's 0x0800 (for IPv4) or 0x86dd (for IPv6).

[The tcpdump.org list of link-layer header types](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) indicates what link-layer types exist.  The numerical values given are those that appear in the "Link-layer header type" field of the file (or in the LinkType field of [an Interface Description Block in a pcapng file](http://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/cgi-bin/xml2rfc.cgi?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcapng/pcapng/master/draft-tuexen-opsawg-pcapng.xml&modeAsFormat=html/ascii&type=ascii#rfc.section.4.2) - libpcap can read some pcapng files, all of the Interface Description Blocks of which must have the same LinkType, and will return the link-layer type in a `pcap_datalink()` call).

The values returned by `pcap_datalink()` are the DLT_ values from the list of link-layer header types, so an Ethernet file (or Ethernet Interface Description Block) will have a value of 1, or LINKTYPE_ETHERNET, in the header, which will be mapped to DLT_EN10MB in the value returned by `pcap_datalink()`.  (In most cases, the LINKTYPE_ values and the corresponding DLT_ values are numerically the same, but there are some exceptions in cases where different operating systems have different numerical values for the same DLT_ type.)  The second capture has LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL in the capture file, so `pcap_datalink()` would return DLT_LINUX_SLL.

The link-layer header type page's descriptions of link-layer header types should help you write code to interpret that link-layer header type's header data.

In addition, as Ron Maupin noted, there may also be VLAN headers after the Ethernet header but before the IP header.

(And, as this is a question by somebody writing a program to read capture files, rather than by somebody designing or maintaining a network, it seems more appropriate for Stack Overflow than Network Engineering.)